# Dojo domConstruct.create

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

While iterating through an array using domConstruct.create I can make a list element like this:

```
domConstruct.create("li", { innerHTML: data }, ul);
```

or html links like this:

```
domConstruct.create("a", { href: "foo.html", innerHTML: "link" }, ul);
```

But how would I construct html that contained both list and href elements? eg:

```
                    <li><a href="#">example1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">example2</a></li>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `li` node that you create as the parent when creating the `a` node.

```
var li = domConstruct.create("li", { innerHTML: data }, ul);
var a = domConstruct.create("a", { href: "foo.html", innerHTML: "link" }, li);
```

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks Craig.